# Why Does My BASH Script Fail When Adding Additional Arguments?

Tags: git, bash

I have a BASH script to go through my Git projects recursively and pull them. We use two branches, master and development. When I change the script to include `&& git checkout development`, my script fails to run and I get this error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

When I remove the `&& git checkout development` part again, the error remains the same even though the script is reverted to its initial state.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git pull && git status" \;
```

And here it is with the Git checkout call (and removing `git status`):

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c "cd \"{}\"/../ && pwd && git checkout development && git pull" \;
```

What is going on here? Is it possibly a red herring that the issue only occurs after changing the script?

Comment: Try this: `find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"/../ && pwd && git checkout develop && git pull' _ '{}' \;`

Comment: That's worked. Thanks! Could you explain why the change makes it work in an answer please? Is the `"$1"` part of it pulling in a command line argument, or doing something different?

Comment: No need to use cd: `find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c 'readlink -f "$1"/../ && git -C "$1"/../ checkout develop && git -C "$1"/../ pull' _ '{}' \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use placeholder `{}` inside command string after `sh -c`.
You can use this `find`:

```
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c \
'cd "$1"/../ && pwd && git checkout develop && git pull' _ '{}' \;
```

Here we are passing dummy `_` to populate `$0` in command line and `{}` is being passed to populate `$1` positional argument.

**Edit based on comment:** 
After tinkering to pass in arguments to the script, I've found it's easiest to export them for the subshell first:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH=$2
export BRANCH
echo "Checking out branch $BRANCH"
find . -type d -name .git -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"/../ && pwd && git checkout "$BRANCH" && git pull; echo "Branch being checked out: $BRANCH"' _ '{}' "$BRANCH" \;
```

Comment: Many thanks. So if I want to pass in a command line argument to tell it which branch to check out, will the `"$1"` interfere, or have to be changed in any way?

Comment: You can pass additional parameters e.g.: `-exec sh -c 'cd "$1"/../ && pwd && git checkout develop && git pull; echo "second value: $2"' _ '{}' "value" \;`